# How to order an array with db data

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
{ [0]=> array(4) { "20" ["date"]=> string(10) "2013-01-25" ["content"]=> string(3) "ref" }
```

and [1], [2]... looks the same.

I wonder how to order my array so [0] is the one the latest date. Changing to timestamp is not an opinion. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : This sorts multi dimensional array

```
$sort = array();
foreach($your_array as $k=>$v) {
    $sort['date'][$k] = $v['date'];
}

array_multisort($sort['date'], SORT_DESC, $your_array);


echo "<pre>";
print_r($your_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

use order by in your query.

```
ORDER BY date
```

Comment: I was thinking if there's a way to do it with the array instead, there's multiple queries

Answer (score 1):

You can use [*usort()*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and write your own comparison function (a function that compares between "objects" - the inner arrays).

Since the dates are written in a way that enables simple string comparison you can do as follows:

```
<?php
function compare($arr1, $arr2) {
   $date1 = $arr1[0];
   $date2 = $arr2[0];
   if($date1 > $date2){
       $ans = 1;
   }
   else if($date2 > $date1){
       $ans = -1;
   }
   else{
       $ans = 0;
   }
   return $ans;
}

$arr = array(array("date"=>"2013-01-25", "content"=>"ref"), 
                array("date"=>"2013-02-25", "content"=>"ref2"), 
                array("date"=>"2013-03-25", "content"=>"ref3")
        );

usort($arr, "compare");
print_r($arr);

?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2013-03-25
            [content] => ref3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2013-02-25
            [content] => ref2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2013-01-25
            [content] => ref
        )

)
```